# Incorrect links on the wiki give 404 errors

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like some of the links on the wiki are obsolete. For instance:

http://wiki.ros.org/imu_drivers links to http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html but should link to http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html instead.

It appears to be the case with all the API links on that page at least:

http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Bool.html is also a 404.

I haven't checked the other wiki pages yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76060/incorrect-links-on-the-wiki-give-404-errors./) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you got unluck when the job was updating. The links are fine now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0